# Sluggish interface with Xubuntu 17.10 guest and Windows 10 host

Tags: xubuntu, virtualization, vmware, performance, gpu

With a pretty powerful PC (i7 7700HQ, 16GB RAM, Intel HD + NVIDIA GF 1050, 512GB PCIE SSD) I am running a Xubuntu 17.10 guest inside a Windows 10 Enterprise host.

The problem is that, even if the guest has 2 CPUs assigned and 6GB of RAM (and the maximum VRAM selectable from VMWare settings), the UI feels sluggish and unresponsive. I am using KDE as DE, in FHD resolution.

The "strange" thing is that proper 3d tasks works as expected (glxgears is butter smooth), but there is a generalized feeling of sluggishness on the whole interface. For example, dragging a window is smooth...ish; pressing "DEL" to delete a file in Dolphin leads to a 2 seconds delay before the confirmation dialog comes up; etc.

What could I do to improve the usability of the machine? I feel very uncomfortable to work with it.

Comment: You say that 3D tasks and dragging windows is smooth, but deleting a file is sluggish. Is it just file-related tasks that are sluggish?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not express myself in the best way I could. It is not that deleting the file is slow, it is Dolphin that is slow in showing the delete dialog. And as far as dragging is concerned, it is not so smooth, it is like if it's 30fps instead of 60. The feeling is a generalized sense of heaviness of the UI.